# How to re-create my local git repository from GitHub

Tags: git, github

I had a git repository on my hard drive, but had to replace my hard drive and lost my repository. I have the repository on GitHub, and I used to `git push origin master` from my local repository.

How do I get my repository back from GitHub and get back to where I was?

Comment: Thanks for the reduced points.  I'm sorry for asking a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply [clone the repository](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone), and you will be back to the last pushed version:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repository.git
```

By default, the master branch will be checked out.

Comment: Do I add the remote origin again after I clone?

Comment: @vintorg No need to do that, unless you were pushing changes to multiple repositories earlier...

Answer (score 1):

Use git clone: If you had any non-pushed local changes they will be gone.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository